# Create random points using Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm applying a function that distributes 500 points within the FeatureCollection.`

```
var getSamples = function(image, samplesFcs, samplesPoints, nsamples, label){

  var samplesCollection = ee.List(samplesFcs).iterate(
    function(sample,totalSample){
        return ee.FeatureCollection(totalSample).merge(sample);
      }
    ,ee.FeatureCollection([]));

    samplesCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(samplesCollection)
    return samplesCollection

    var randomPoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(samplesCollection, nsamples, 1989)

      samplesPoints.forEach(function(points) {
        randomPoints = randomPoints.merge(points);
      })

     return randomPoints
}
```

however it is wrong, after all, when I give a print on the console to check how many points were sampled inside the Features, the number returned is about Features within the FeatureCollection, as opposed to the number of samples

```
var test = getSamples(addndvi_2018,class4,class4Points,nsamples)
print(teste.size(),'samples Vegetation')
```

Can anyone point to where I'm doing wrong [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/8a9be5346fcf74e6deaeaecae9430425)?

Comment: + your link requires a login. This is a Question and Answer Site.

Answer (score 1):

At line 36 you have `nSamples` instead of `nsamples`.